# Text right rotation and right alignment

Tags: html, css, rotation

I need to do something like that.

[image]

But I don't know how to align the text2 to the right

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="outer outer-l rotate-l">
            <p>text1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="">
        </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="outer outer-r rotate-r">
            <p>text2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

```
.main-wrapper {height: 100vh;}

.outer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 50%;
}

.rotate-l {
    transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(0) rotate(-90deg);
}

.rotate-r {
}
```

What should I do with the translate for .rotate-r?.

Comment: check [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqGZNq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rotate the second content with `90deg` and use `float:right;`

Try this

```css
.main-wrapper {height: 100vh; width:100%;}

.outer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.image-container{text-align:center;}
.rotate-l {
    transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(0) rotate(-90deg);
}
.rotate-r {
  transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(-16px) rotate(90deg);
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="outer outer-l rotate-l">
            <p>text1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="">
            blah blah blah
        </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="outer outer-r rotate-r">
            <p>text2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just rotate 90deg (instead of -90deg), and keep the rest like rotate-l

```
.rotate-r {
    transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(0) rotate(90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

used  `transform: rotate(90deg);` for the 2nd content

```css
.main-wrapper {height: 100vh;}

.outer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 50%;
}

.rotate-l {
    transform:  translateX(0%) translateY(0) rotate(-90deg);
}

.rotate-r {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.col-md-8{background-color: black;
    height: 250px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="outer outer-l rotate-l">
            <p>text1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="">
        </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="outer outer-r rotate-r">
            <p>text2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```